# My C# code can't send mail but outlook 2k7 can

Tags: c#, sendmail, smtpclient

I have write C# code to send mail (my company mail). I tried with gmail and it working but with my company mail is not.

I sure the smtp server is running and port 465 opened since I can send mail by outlook 2k7 with the same account, telnet smtp.domain 465 ok.

When i run the code it throw exception "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has time out."

Here is my c# code:

```
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("ID@domain", "Display Name");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("ID@domain", "Display Name");
        const string subject = "Test mail";
        const string body = "Test mail";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.domain",
            Port = 465,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID", "pass"),
            Timeout=15000                
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body,

        })
        {
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any one know or have same problem that fixed please help me. Thanks so much!

Comment: Is it a desktop application? If so are you running it with Run As Adminstrator?

Comment: Yes, it is. I had tried run as administrator right but the problem still has.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing setting EnableSsl = false in your SmtpClient instance.

Comment: The problem still has after I change property EanableSsl = false

Answer (score 0):

You can change this code and reuse this code:

```
        public static void sendEmail(string address, string subject, string message)
        {
            string email = "yourEmail";
            string password = "yourPass";

            var loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
            var msg = new MailMessage();
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", portNumber);

            msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = message;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
        }
```

Comment: I had tried your code (Babak Abad) but it still throw the above exception. I think the smtp server refused my connection since security problems. May be my code not be trusted as outlook 2k7! This is my option.

Comment: I'm using this code in my project now! So may be your firewall or anti virus block your application except outlook. Check your password and server strings. then check that is your server allow to send email from custom programs? I know how edit gmail settings.If you are using gmail servers I can help you to edit it.